# Is there a way to extend how deep Intellij's real-time and autocomplete features look into import statements?

Tags: intellij-idea, go

My import line looks like this:

`github.schq.secious.com/Company/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/boltdb/bolt`

My code compiles and my tests pass, but the real-time help that I get from Intellij tells me the methods on my bolt object don't exist. Autocomplete doesn't work on them either which causes a lot of headache if I try to ignore the false errors.

If I copy boltdb to the classic location and import it accordingly

`github.com/boltdb/bolt`

My autocomplete and real-time notifications work just fine and my code continues to compile and pass its tests.

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: The version is 0.9.562

Comment: Hmm, latest alpha build, OK. What happens when you go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Language and Frameworks` -> `Go`. Are the `Libraries` configured correctly? Is the SDK set?
(you may have to look for the settings menu; I'm using WebStorm, not IDEA)

Comment: I have my [GOPATH] pointing to my go directory for projects and I have a second entry for my go binaries (/usr/local/go as I am running CentOS)

Comment: Can you please add more details about your setup? Eventually some screenshots? Also you can report the issue here: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/new and you might be able to get more help faster.

Comment: I can do that. Other people on my team have been seeing the same issue, so maybe it is a bug. Will get more information soon.